# Linker Errors when linking precompiled static library

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, linker

I have a big project written in C++ using the Qt libraries and I have another library that is written in Java. Now I would like to write an android application that can use both libraries.

Because I don't want to fiddle with Qt libraries in android studio (please tell me if there is an easier way), I decided it would be easiest to create a static qt installation for android, precompile the project using qt creator (packing all the dependencies with it) and then import the precompiled library in android studio. Everything has worked, except for the linking step. I suspect that this has something to do with all the `extern "C"` stuff.

Side note: I couldn't get qt to spit out a shared object file, but I managed to get a static library full of object files (even the Qt ones).

I get linker errors like these:

```
../../../../lib/armeabi-v7a/libapi.a(api.o):api.cpp:function IfStreamQIODeviceWrapper::seek(long long): error: undefined reference to 'std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<mbstate_t>)'
../../../../lib/armeabi-v7a/libapi.a(api.o):api.cpp:function TestAPI_loadFile: error: undefined reference to 'QIODevice::QIODevice()'
../../../../lib/armeabi-v7a/libapi.a(api.o):api.cpp:function TestAPI_loadFile: error: undefined reference to 'std::istream::seekg(long long, std::_Ios_Seekdir)'
../../../../lib/armeabi-v7a/libapi.a(api.o):api.cpp:function TestAPI_loadFile: error: undefined reference to 'std::istream::tellg()'
```

But libapi.a does actually contain those symbols (according to nm):

`nm -C libapi.a|grep -n5 std::istream::seekg`

```
172-         U std::istream::read(char*, int)
173:         U std::istream::seekg(std::fpos<mbstate_t>)
174:         U std::istream::seekg(long long, std::_Ios_Seekdir)
175-         U std::istream::tellg()
176-00000001 W std::_List_base<Ms::SynthesizerGroup, 
std::allocator<Ms::SynthesizerGroup> >::_M_clear()
177-00000001 W std::_List_base<Ms::IdValue, 
std::allocator<Ms::IdValue> >::_M_clear()
```

So it doesn't really seem to be limited to Qt related functions, because I somehow get linker errors for things that should be in the standard library. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: **`U`** means that the library *does not* contain the symbol, but needs it to link properly. This looks as if your prebuilt `libapi.a` was not built with NDK toolchain.

Comment: @Alex Cohn oh. Allow me to check back to see if the qt stuff is really contained in there. That would explain it... Thanks!

Comment: @AlexCohn It does indeed appear that the QT libraries are not packet into the static library as I initially thought. But I don't quite get why it seems to be having trouble with the standard library. Is there some kind of g++ flag I have to enable?

Comment: Btw, I compiled the library with a standalone toolchain built using the ndk, that might have been an issue but I don't really feel like porting all the code to work with the native ndk.

Comment: The standalone toolchain is ok, but it's delicate: one can easily misconfigure the build to fall back to the system (not cross-compiling) toolchain, especially on Linux. I am afraid that's what happened in your case.

Comment: Actually I got the linker problems to go away. I had to configure cmake to use gnustl instead of the clang libc++, and then I had to add the qt libraries in reverse order (not sure why). However, it now complains that it can't find the android platform plugin, and when I add it in, it somehow gets stuck in JNI_OnLoad. I think it's easier for me to try Qt Android Extras. But thanks for the info with nm; If you want to post that as an answer to the question where the linker problems come from, go ahead, I'll accept it.